# On-demand SSH Socks proxy through systemd user units with socket-activation doesn't restart as wished

Tags: ssh, systemd, proxy, socks, socket-activation

To reach an isolated network I use an [ssh](/questions/tagged/ssh) `-D` [socks](/questions/tagged/socks) [proxy](/questions/tagged/proxy).

In order to avoid having to type the details every time I added them to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
$ awk '/Host socks-proxy/' RS= ~/.ssh/config
Host socks-proxy
  Hostname pcit
  BatchMode yes
  RequestTTY no
  Compression yes
  DynamicForward localhost:9118
```

Then I created a [systemd-user](/questions/tagged/systemd-user) service unit definition file:

```
$ cat ~/.config/systemd/user/SocksProxy.service 
[Unit]
Description=SocksProxy Over Bridge Host

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh -Nk socks-proxy

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

I let the daemon reload the new service definitions, enabled the new service, started it, checked its status, and verified, that it is listening:

```
$ systemctl --user daemon-reload
$ systemctl --user list-unit-files | grep SocksP
SocksProxy.service   disabled

$ systemctl --user enable SocksProxy.service
Created symlink from ~/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants/SocksProxy.service to ~/.config/systemd/user/SocksProxy.service.

$ systemctl --user start SocksProxy.service 
$ systemctl --user status SocksProxy.service 
● SocksProxy.service - SocksProxy Over Bridge Host
   Loaded: loaded (/home/alex/.config/systemd/user/SocksProxy.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-08-03 10:45:29 CEST; 2s ago
 Main PID: 26490 (ssh)
   CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/SocksProxy.service
           └─26490 /usr/bin/ssh -Nk socks-proxy

$ netstat -tnlp | grep 118
tcp     0    0 127.0.0.1:9118        0.0.0.0:*             LISTEN     
tcp6    0    0 ::1:9118              :::*                  LISTEN
```

This works as intended. Then I wanted to avoid having to manually start the service, or running it permanently with [autossh](/questions/tagged/autossh), by using [systemd](/questions/tagged/systemd) [socket-activation](/questions/tagged/socket-activation) for on-demand (re-)spawning. That didn't work, I think (my version of) `ssh` cannot receive socket file-descriptors.

I found the documentation ([1](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation.html),[2](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation2.html)), and [an example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352495/systemd-on-demand-start-of-services-like-postgresql-and-mysql-that-do-not-yet-s) for using the [`systemd-socket-proxyd`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-socket-proxyd.html)-tool to create 2 "wrapper" services, a "service" and a "socket":

```
$ cat ~/.config/systemd/user/SocksProxyHelper.socket 
[Unit]
Description=On Demand Socks proxy into Work

[Socket]
ListenStream=8118
#BindToDevice=lo
#Accept=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target

$ cat ~/.config/systemd/user/SocksProxyHelper.service 
[Unit]
Description=On demand Work Socks tunnel
After=network.target SocksProxyHelper.socket
Requires=SocksProxyHelper.socket SocksProxy.service
After=SocksProxy.service

[Service]
#Type=simple
#Accept=false
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-socket-proxyd 127.0.0.1:9118
TimeoutStopSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

$ systemctl --user daemon-reload
```

This *seems* to work, until `ssh` dies or gets killed. Then it won't re-spawn at the next connection attempt when it should.

#### Questions:

1. Can /usr/bin/ssh really not accept systemd-passed sockets? Or only newer versions? Mine is the [one from up2date Debian 8.9](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/openssh-client).
2. Can only units of root use the `BindTodevice` option?
3. Why is my proxy service not respawning correctly on first new connection after the old tunnel dies?
4. Is this the right way to set-up an "on-demand ssh socks proxy"? If, not, how do you do it?

Comment: `autossh` should take care of reconnecting in case the connection fails (though it is not the system-way).

Comment: @Jakuje : Thx for the comment, but I do not want the connection to be permanent. I want it to be spawned when I use it, and then (ideally after a no-data-sent-in-x-minutes timeout) self-terminate. Also, my previous solution used `autossh`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> - Can /usr/bin/ssh really not accept systemd-passed sockets?

I think that's not too surprising, considering:

- OpenSSH is an OpenBSD project
- systemd only supports the Linux kernel
- systemd support would need to be explicitly added to OpenSSH, as an optional/build-time dependency, so it would probably be a hard sell.

---

> - Can only units of root use the `BindTodevice` option?

User systemd instances are generally pretty isolated, and e.g. can not communicate with the main pid-0 instance. Things like depending on system units from user unit files are not possible.

The documentation for `BindToDevice` mentions:

> Note that setting this parameter might result in additional dependencies to be added to the unit (see above).

Due to the above-mentioned restriction, we can imply that the option doesn't work from user systemd instances.

---

> - Why is my proxy service not respawning correctly on first new connection after the old tunnel dies?

As I understand, the chain of events is as follows:

- `SocksProxyHelper.socket` is started.
- A SOCKS client connects to localhost:8118.
- systemd starts `SocksProxyHelper.service`.
- As a dependency of `SocksProxyHelper.service`, systemd also starts `SocksProxy.service`.
- `systemd-socket-proxyd` accepts the systemd socket, and forwards its data to
  `ssh`.
- `ssh` dies or is killed.
- systemd notices, and places `SocksProxy.service` into a inactive state, but does nothing.
- `SocksProxyHelper.service` keeps running and accepting connections, but fails to connect to `ssh`, as it is no longer running.

The fix is to add `BindsTo=SocksProxy.service` to `SocksProxyHelper.service`. Quoting its documentation (emphasis added):

> Configures requirement dependencies, very similar in style to `Requires=`. However, this dependency type is stronger: in addition to the effect of `Requires=` it declares that **if the unit bound to is stopped, this unit will be stopped too**. This means a unit bound to another unit that suddenly enters inactive state will be stopped too. Units can suddenly, unexpectedly enter inactive state for different reasons: the **main process of a service unit might terminate on its own choice**, the backing device of a device unit might be unplugged or the mount point of a mount unit might be unmounted without involvement of the system and service manager.
>
> When used in conjunction with `After=` on the same unit the behaviour of `BindsTo=` is even stronger. In this case, the unit bound to **strictly has to be in active state for this unit to also be in active state**. This not only means a unit bound to another unit that suddenly enters inactive state, but also one that is bound to another unit that gets skipped due to a failed condition check (such as `ConditionPathExists=`, `ConditionPathIsSymbolicLink=`, … — see below) will be stopped, should it be running. Hence, in many cases it is best to combine `BindsTo=` with `After=`.

---

> - Is this the right way to set-up an "on-demand ssh socks proxy"? If, not, how do you do it?

There's probably no "right way". This method has its advantages (everything being "on-demand") and disadvantages (dependency on systemd, the first connection not getting through because ssh hasn't begun listening yet). Perhaps implementing systemd socket activation support in autossh would be a better solution.

Comment: I have added `BindsTo=SocksProxy.service` to the Unit section of the file `~/.config/systemd/user/SocksProxyHelper.service`, after the `After=SocksProxy.service` line. Manually restarting the SocksProxy Service is now not required anymore, when SSH dies/gets_killed. Is there a way for systemd to "hold" the initial connection, so that it does not get a TCP reset?

Comment: @Vladimir Panteleev one point I would like to clarify: support for systemd socket activation can be implemented relatively easily by parsing `$LISTEN_FDS` without adding a dependency on `sd_listen_fds()`, so it may still be a hard sell, but not too hard.

Comment: @AlexStragies To confuse matters more, the naming scheme in this conversation as a whole is misleading. What you are calling SocksProxyHelper is a proxy service. What you are calling SocksProxy is proxied service. Coupled with the fact that your proxied service is running an executable offering a SOCKS5 Proxy, it gets confusing really fast.

Answer (score 7):

For future reference, i'm pasting below the `systemd --user` configuration files
for on-demand ssh-tunnel using `systemd-socket-proxyd` daemon,
with various enhancements and explanation comments:

#### `~/.config/systemd/user/ssh-tunnel-proxy.socket`

```
[Unit]
Description=Socket-activation for SSH-tunnel

[Socket]
ListenStream=1000

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

#### `~/.config/systemd/user/ssh-tunnel-proxy.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Socket-activation proxy for SSH tunnel

## Stop also when stopped listening for socket-activation.
BindsTo=ssh-tunnel-proxy.socket
After=ssh-tunnel-proxy.socket

## Stop also when ssh-tunnel stops/breaks
#  (otherwise, could not restart).
BindsTo=ssh-tunnel.service
After=ssh-tunnel.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-socket-proxyd --exit-idle-time=500s localhost:1001
```

#### `~/.config/systemd/user/ssh-tunnel.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Tunnel to SSH server

## Stop-when-idle is controlled by `--exit-idle-time=` in proxy.service
#  (from `man systemd-socket-proxyd`)
StopWhenUnneeded=true

[Service]
Type=simple
## Prefixed with `-` not to mark service as failed on net-fails;
#  will be restarted on-demand by socket-activation.
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/ssh -kaxNT -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes  hostname_in_ssh_config  -L 1001:localhost:2000
## Delay enough time to allow for ssh-authentication to complete
#  so tunnel has been established before proxy process attaches to it,
#  or else the first SYN request will be lost.
ExecStartPost=/bin/sleep 2
```

#### Customizations

In the scripts above, you have to replace the following strings:

- **`1000`** - (`ssh-tunnel-proxy.socket` file) 
  what *(host:)port* to listen locally for socket-activation of the tunnel,
  e.g. to emulate a local MYSql port.
- **`1001`** - (`ssh-tunnel-proxy.service` & `ssh-tunnel.service` files) 
  what local *(host:)port* to use when proxy-forwarding to ssh service-process;
  just choose an unused port.
- **`hostname_in_ssh_config`** - (`ssh-tunnel.service` file) 
  the host-group to connect to, referred in your [ssh-config](https://superuser.com/questions/349007/grouping-hosts-in-ssh-config)
  (any SOCKS configuration belong there).
- **`localhost:2000`** - (`ssh-tunnel.service` file) 
  the  ssh tunnel's remote *host:port* endpoint, e.g. where the remote MYSql binds to.
- **x2 delay timings** (`ssh-tunnel-proxy.service` & `ssh-tunnel.service` files) 
  they are explained in the comments.
- **`ssh-tunnel-...`** - (the prefix of all unit-files) 
  make it descriptive of your need for the tunnel, e.g. `mysql-tunnel-...`.
- **SSH** - (in the `Description=` directives of all unit-files) 
  make it descriptive of your need for the tunnel, e.g. `MYSql`.

### Commands for controlling the tunnel

```bsh
# After any edits.
systemctl --user daemon-reload
# If socket's unit-file has been edited.
systemctl --user restart ssh-tunnel-proxy.socket

# To start listening for on-demand activation of the tunnel
systemctl --user start ssh-tunnel.socket

# To enable on-demand tunnel on Boot
systemctl --user enable ssh-tunnel-proxy.socket

# To gracefully stop tunnel (any cmd will do)
systemctl --user stop ssh-tunnel.service
systemctl --user stop ssh-tunnel-proxy.service

# To gracefully stop & disable tunnel (till next reboot)
systemctl --user stop ssh-tunnel-proxy.socket

# To view the health of the tunnel
systemctl --user status ssh-tunnel-proxy.{socket,service} ssh-tunnel

# To reset tunnel after errors (both cmds may be needed)
systemctl --user reset-failed ssh-tunnel ssh-tunnel-proxy
systemctl --user restart ssh-tunnel-proxy.socket
```

Comment: Excellent! I'm using this for plain point-to-point tunneling myself, not SOCKS, and it seems to be working as expected so far, except for one little detail.  

I'm pretty sure `-L 1002:localhost:2000` should read `-L 1001:…`. The port that `systemd-socket-proxyd` forwards *to* has to match the local end of the ssh tunnel in order for any proxied connections to work.

Comment: Thanks! This excellent answer helped me a lot!

Here's a small improvement I made. Instead of using a port, use a unix socket (`/tmp/ssh-tunnel` for example). I generally prefer this over just port numbers. Then, this allows to replace the sleep, which may not be enough and may be too much, with waiting for the file: 
`ExecStartPost=bash -c "while [ ! -e /tmp/ssh-tunnel ]; do sleep 0.1; done"`

Comment: Thank you @noam.  I suspect that `systemd` has [options to avoid the use of a bash sleep-loop](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html).

Answer (score 3):

Due to the reputation system, I'm not able to comment @ankostis solution...

> I suspect that systemd has options to avoid the use of a bash sleep-loop

Yes, there is systemd-notify.

Also incorporating @noam suggestion to use use a socket between systemd-socket-proxyd and ssh to not waste local ports, it would look like the following:

**~/.config/systemd/user/ssh-tunnel-proxy.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Socket-activation proxy for SSH tunnel

## Stop also when stopped listening for socket-activation.
BindsTo=ssh-tunnel-proxy.socket
After=ssh-tunnel-proxy.socket

## Stop also when ssh-tunnel stops/breaks
#  (otherwise, could not restart).
BindsTo=ssh-tunnel.service
After=ssh-tunnel.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-socket-proxyd --exit-idle-time=500s ${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/ssh-tunnel-proxy
```

**~/.config/systemd/user/ssh-tunnel.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Tunnel to SSH server

## Stop-when-idle is controlled by `--exit-idle-time=` in proxy.service
#  (from `man systemd-socket-proxyd`)
StopWhenUnneeded=true

[Service]
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all
## Prefixed with `-` not to mark service as failed on net-fails;
#  will be restarted on-demand by socket-activation.
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/ssh -kaxNT -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o ControlMaster=no -o StreamLocalBindUnlink=yes -o PermitLocalCommand=yes -o LocalCommand="systemd-notify --ready" hostname_in_ssh_config -L ${XDG_RUNTIME_DIR}/ssh-tunnel-proxy:localhost:2000
```

The ssh_config man page says about LocalCommand "Specifies a command to execute on the local machine after successfully connecting to the server".

`ControlMaster=no` ensures that the ssh session never gets a master in case multiplexing is used, since it's town down automatically and would kill all other multiplexed ssh sessions to the same host.

Finally, it might be a good idea to bind the socket port to localhost.

**~/.config/systemd/user/ssh-tunnel-proxy.socket**

```
[Unit]
Description=Socket-activation for SSH-tunnel

[Socket]
ListenStream=127.0.0.1:1000
ListenStream=[::1]:1000

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! +1. I'll give your suggestions a spin :)

Answer (score 2):

Still testing this (as I am writing this answer, I am using it), but I think the missing ingredient is `-o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes` as an option to your `ssh` binary.