# Openssh socks server with socket activation using systemd

Tags: ssh, fedora, systemd, ssh-tunneling

I have following setup:

```
tunnel.service

[Unit]
Description=Setup a secure tunnel to %I
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh -N -D 0.0.0.0:1080 myhost.name
User=snoopy


# Restart every >2 seconds to avoid StartLimitInterval failure
RestartSec=5
Restart=always
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And I want to start this service only when system have incoming connection to it!

I was read some docs about systemd socket activation, but it's like I can't open port using -D option of ssh

PS. Fedora 27 inside virtualbox

Comment: To be clear, when sometimes connects to port 1080 on your machine, you want to start up an SSH tunnel, which then forwards the connection on to `myhost.name`?

Comment: Yes! I have firefox addon that uses socks proxy for some urls.

Answer (score 2):

You may retrofit daemons without native support for socket-activation using `systemd-socket-proxyd`, as described in [this SO reply](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/635178/156357) specifically for SSH.